# Holding off displaying figure window in Matlab

Tags: matlab

The following piece of code is from the great book "An Introduction to Programming and Numerical Methods in MATLAB" by S.R. Otto and J.P. Denier

x = 0:pi/20:pi;

n = length(x);

r = 1:n/7:n;

y = x.ˆ2+3;

plot(x,y,’b’,x(r),y(r),’r*’)

...

Code continues from here specifying x axis and y axis labels and so on. When I start to write the code in command window, as soon as I put the last round bracket for plot command, Matlab returns figure window with the plot, without me having a chance to insert x and y axis labels and so on. How do I get the plot with everything complete?

Comment: Once the figure has been created, you can add axis labels and stuff with commands like `xlabel`, etc.

Comment: I was wondering if I can get a plot once and with final appearance, however after the generation of the figure, adding title and label stuff is fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab's [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) for the `plot` function contains the following code example:

```
figure
plot(x,y,'Color',[0,0.7,0.9])

title('2-D Line Plot')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('cos(5x)')
```

I believe this is the standard way to do it in Matlab --- axis labels, title, etc. are added with additional commands after calling the `plot` function.